# Clangd: treat files with non-standard extensions as headers

Tags: c++, c, header-files, file-extension, clangd

I am working with an old C code base where there are header files with non-standard extensions such as `.s`, `.e`, etc instead of `.h`

For compatibility reasons I cannot rename these files.

Currently these files are causing the following error message in clangd:

> Unable to handle compilation, expected exactly one compiler job in ''clang(fe_expected_compiler_job)

Which I interpret as meaning "0 compiler job found" i.e. clangd treats these files as `.c` source files.

**How can I get clangd to treat them as header files ?**

Answer (score 0):

I found that `compile_commands.json` can be used to instruct clangd to treat a file with an arbitrary name as a header, using the option to [generate a precompiled header file (PCH file)](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#generating-a-pch-file):

```
[
    {
        "directory": "path/to/directory",
        "file": "path/to/file.e",
        "arguments": ["clang", "-x", "c-header", "path/to/file.e"]
    }
]
```

For a C++ header you would have to use `c++-header` instead of `c-header`.

I tested this on clangd 13.0.0.

I got help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69215513/4669135).