# vscode-clangd with .inl files

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clangd

I know there are many questions about this but non seem to be what I need or are not clear enough.
I'm using visual studio code for my c++ project. At first I was using intellisense which worked fine except for the fact that I was missing the call hierarchy. I heard that with the [visual studio clangd extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=llvm-vs-code-extensions.vscode-clangd) you could have this call hierarchy and I indeed do have it, but now my *.inl files are not parsed: the outline tab in vs states `No symbols found in document 'name.inl'`, if I try ctrl+click to get to a function or variable definition it just ends up at the top of the inline file.

I found [this](https://reviews.llvm.org/D67025) to add to clangd to recognize an *.inl file as header file, but I don't know where to find the Types.cpp file.

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71471967/clangd-treat-files-with-non-standard-extensions-as-headers) which says to add the files to the `compile_commands.json` but that also doesn't work I would say for two reasons: 1) I'm using `CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS` to generate the `compile_commands.json` 2) there are too many *.inl files in the project to all add them manually.

I also found [this](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang-tools-extra/blob/fd2d6d99444e790680fbfec823f16e7a45a6d1b3/clangd/clients/clangd-vscode/src/extension.ts#L34) which looks like the clangd extension source code but again I don't know where to find the file `extension.ts`

Any help for making it such that my *.inl files are recognized is highly appreciated (and please be specific since it appears I'm a nooby and do not understand much surrounding this topic).

P.S. I'm not interested in compilation that works fine, as far as I understood we are not using clangd for that but gcc via CMake.

Comment: Some years ago I decided to turn intellisense off because of numerous problems. I don't miss it.

Answer (score 2):

While I haven't tried it, I suspect you need **two** different things to make this work:

1. Get your editor to understand that `.inl` files should be processed by clangd (as opposed to some other language server). For vscode, that means patching the vscode-clangd client in the [place](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang-tools-extra/blob/fd2d6d99444e790680fbfec823f16e7a45a6d1b3/clangd/clients/clangd-vscode/src/extension.ts#L34) you linked to.

   To do this you'd need to:

   - Check out the client's source code, which
     now lives at https://github.com/clangd/vscode-clangd
   - Make the code change
   - Follow the steps in the vscode-clangd project's README to build the
     client plugin (this will produce a `.vsix` file)
   - Install the locally built plugin with vscode's `Extensions: Install from VSIX...` command

   **UPDATE**: There's an easier way to do this which doesn't require patching the client:

   - Open vscode settings
   - Filter for `Files: Associations`
   - In the section that comes up, add an item associating `*.inl` with the language `c++`
2. Get clangd to understand that it should process the `.inl` file as if it was a C++ header. This requires **either** modifying your `compile_commands.json` to contain entries for your `.inl` files, **or** patching the clangd *server* with the [patch you linked](https://reviews.llvm.org/D67025).

   The `compile_commands.json` file approach is probably easier. You don't need to modify the file manually, you can post-process the file produced by CMake with a script. In particular, have a look at the [CompDB](https://github.com/Sarcasm/compdb) tool, which is designed to add entries for header files to a `compile_commands.json`. It may just work out of the box for `.inl` files; if not, consider filing an issue with the CompDB project, asking for `.inl` support to be added.

   If you want to go with patching the clangd server, that requires checking out the entire [LLVM project](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/), making the change, then building using the instructions [here](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/main/clang-tools-extra/clangd#building-and-testing-clangd). You can point vscode to your locally built clangd using the `"clangd.path"` setting.

For additional assistance, feel free to ask questions in the #clangd channel of the [LLVM Discord](https://discord.gg/xS7Z362).

---

If you get this to work, consider making some contributions that would allow this to work out of the box. For example, consider submitting a pull request to the vscode-clangd project with the change you had to make.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed comments, I'm trying your steps but so far unsuccessful. For your first point bullet 3 you say "Follow the steps in the readme to build the client plugin", but I don't see any steps in the readme to build the plugin. Can you help?

Comment: I wish this was just as easy as in eclipse were I could just go to Preferences>C/C++>File Types and add the *.inl as C++ Header File there. I'm starting to doubt whether vs is actually better.

Comment: @C.Binair My bad, the instructions are in the DEVELOPING.md document: https://github.com/clangd/vscode-clangd/blob/master/DEVELOPING.md. Also, they don't seem to mention the command to package the extension into a `.vsix` file, which is `npm run package`.

Comment: Oke I think I'm stupid. It doesn't look like I can make the change listed [here](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang-tools-extra/blob/fd2d6d99444e790680fbfec823f16e7a45a6d1b3/clangd/clients/clangd-vscode/src/extension.ts#L34) because the extension.ts from [here](https://github.com/clangd/vscode-clangd/blob/master/src/extension.ts) looks completely different and doesn't have that line.

Comment: @C.Binair You're not stupid, codebases just change over time :) In this case, it looks like the code in question was refactored in [this commit](https://github.com/clangd/vscode-clangd/commit/9e7156747e7cb4cf61e69a6dfd600128b85f6ace) to not list individual extensions, but instead rely on vscode's file associations.

This means there's actually a way to solve the first part in a way that's more like Eclipse: go to vscode settings, filter for "Files: Associations", and in the section that comes up, add an item mapping `*.inl` to `c++`.